# How to make a CSS transition loop once?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make some text fade to a new colour and then back to it's original colour.

```
#sidebar2:target .phonenumber { 
    -o-transition:0.7s;
    -ms-transition:0.7s;
    -moz-transition:0.7s;
    -webkit-transition:0.7s;
    transition:0.7s;
    color: yellow;
}
```

Currently it just goes to the new colour and stays like that. How can I adapt this code so that is does what I want? Any help is appreciated!

EDIT:

I am using :target so that when a user clicks on a same page link, the part of the text that I'm linking to is highlighted. I would like the text to fade to a different colour and then back again

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle of what you currently have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm fairly certain it is not possible to loop a transition, you are able to transition from one state to another but not back again in a single transition.

To achieve the result you are looking for you would use an animation instead.

First set up the animation keyframes:

```
@keyframes glowyellow {
  0% { color: auto; }
  50% { color: yellow; }
  100% { color: auto; }
}
```

Then to use this on your element:

```
#sidebar2:target .phonenumber {
  animation: glowyellow 1.4s linear;
}
```

Use vendor prefixes to support browsers as you are doing in your example.

Here is a [fiddle as an example](http://jsfiddle.net/qzEFL/).

Comment: Nice one stuart +1 but it's better to define some color or use `inherit` instead of auto

Comment: Thanks, I think `inherit` will use the color from the parent element, whereas using `auto` allows you to use any initial color that was previously set for the element. This fiddle shows that using `inherit` "steals" the parents color definition rather than keeping the elements original color. http://jsfiddle.net/qzEFL/1/

Comment: That's perfect thanks Stuart. Just out of interest how well supported is @keyframes?

Comment: NP, literature at MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/@keyframes#Browser_Compatibility, supported FF, Chrome, Safari, Opera, from a couple of versions back, IE 10

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8C3We/)

```
span {
    color: #000;
    transition: color 1s;
    /* Not using proprietary codes here, you can add it if you need */
}

span:hover {
    color: #aaa;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am using :target so that when a user clicks on a same page link, that part of the page is highlighted. I would like the text to fade to a different colour and then back again

Answer (score 1):

8 years late, but there is a "*psudo-selector*" for visited links: `:visited`

(It's actually a **pseudo class**)
Just modify the attributes you want from there. No need for animation and transitions.